# Choosing a data type as a parameter?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to specify a data type (specifically: int, text, byte, char) as a parameter?
For example: (this doesn't work)

```
public void myclass(System.Object ChoosenType)
{
    switch (ChoosenType)
        case System.Text:
        case System.Byte:
        case System.Int32:
        case Sustem.Char:
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? Looks like a pretty bad code smell to me.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. I am somewhat new so my vocabulary is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by using the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) class. However, you can't use a switch statement since you can't switch on `Type` objects.

> CS0151 A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

You also need to change your comparison method, as the "type name" of a type is not a `Type` object. You have to use `typeof`:

```
public void someMethod(Type theType)
{
    if (theType == typeof(Int32))
    {
    }
    else if (theType == typeof(Char))
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Also note that `System.Text` is not a type, but a namespace. `System.String` on the other hand *is* a type.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting that in addition to using the `Type` class, you could replace the `System.Int32` with it's alias, `int`.  This works because `int` is really just a "nickname" for the fully qualified `System.Int32` class.

ex-

```
public void myClass(Type x)
{
    if (x == typeof(int))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int");
    }
    else if (x == typeof(bool))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bool");
    }
    else if (x == typeof(string))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string");
    }
    //additional Type tests can go here
    else Console.WriteLine("Invalid type");
}
```